# Problem linking netpbm library

Tags: c++, linux, linker

Hi stackoverflow community now I am part of you with my first question.
My problem is quite simple:
I want to use the netpbm library in a c++ program but can't link.

```
g++ test.cpp -o test -lnetpbm
/tmp/ccZsqYHK.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0x39): undefined reference to ppm_readppm(_IO_FILE*, int*, int*, unsigned int*)
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

As you can see I already linked netpbm but the error does not vanish.
I already searched google for hours but ran out of queries to enter.
And no one seems to have this problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ppm.h is not c++ friendly. Try  including it as follows:

```
extern "C" {
#include <ppm.h>
}
```

Comment: Thanks that one did the trick. Btw I used pam.h instead of ppm.h